# fragment manager in navigation drawer error

Tags: android

I am using Fragment manager in navigation drawer in android studio.I typed the following code as

```
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(content_frame, fragment).commit();
```

It shows red line below ***fragment*** in above code.
The screenshot is also uploaded.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VFTz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Change `getFragmentManager()` for `getSupportFragmentManager()`and import supportV4

Comment: delete or clean library fragmentManager() and import only support V4 – Domi mtz 1 hour ago